# How to override appsetting.production.json file's values from app service configuration > application setting section?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have ASP.NET core app and some app settings are stored in application.production.json files I want them to get overridden from the app service > configuration > application setting section.

I have added the key/Value pairs but those are not getting overridden. Is there a way to do so?

Thanks.

Comment: What are all settings you are trying to configure?

Comment: There are some custom setting that my application is needed which should only be applicable for prod env and not dev env

Comment: Could you please share your `appsettings.production.json` and `Application settings` in App Service Configuration section.

Comment: Also please share your `Program.cs` file.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below lines of code in `Program.cs` to read the environment specific config values.

```cs
var environmentJSON = $"appsettings.{app.Environment}.json";
IConfigurationBuilder configBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true)
    .AddJsonFile(environmentJSON, true);
```

***My appsettings.Production.json***

```cs
{
  "AppSettings": {
    "MyValue": "Production"
  }
}
```

***My Program.cs***

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
var app = builder.Build();
var environmentJSON = $"appsettings.{app.Environment}.json";
IConfigurationBuilder configBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true)
    .AddJsonFile(environmentJSON, true);
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.Run();
```

***Reading AppSettings Value in Index.cshtml***
In `HomeController`, add the `IConfiguration`

```cs
  private readonly IConfiguration _config;
    public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var result = _config.GetValue<string>("AppSettings:MyValue"); 
            ViewBag.Result = result;
            return View();
        }
```

***Index.cshtml***

```cs
<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
    <br />
    <h3>@ViewBag.Result</h3>
</div>
```

I have Published the App to Azure.
Initially I have not set any value in `Azure App Configuration` => `App Settings`, So the value which is set in `appsettings.Production.json` will be displayed.

[image]

Add the new `Key-Value` with same name as in `appsettings.production.json` in Application settings.

***My Azure App Settings***
[image]

***New Output***

[image]